# Long- and Multi-format Path Manipulation Library?

Tags: c++, c, path, path-manipulation

Is there any path open-source manipulation library which supports all of the following?

- Unrestricted path lengths (i.e. the only restriction should be from the range of `size_t`, **not** arbitrary limitations like 256 characters)
- Basic manipulations like canonicalization, the equivalent of `basename`, `dirname`, getting the file extension, getting the root, etc.
- **All** valid Windows-style paths and file names, such as `\Rooted`, `Dir/`, `C:\Dir/foo`, `File`, `\\Computer\Dir/File`, `\\.\C:`, `Foo\./.\Bar:ADS`, or `\\?\C:\Dir\Escaped:ADS:$DATA`

  - I believe this should also cover POSIX-style paths, but if not, those should work too

I'd prefer C++, but C is also fine.

Comment: Well, definitely *not* boost.filesystem. It operates on very syntactic level and assumes that the path syntax is close to POSIX (e.g. extension is from the last dot to the end of the string)...

Comment: @ybungalobill: Indeed, Boost doesn't work. But for your particular example: *Isn't* the extension from the last dot to the end of the string? Or do you mean it's because it does not take into account paths like `\.foo`?

Comment: I think you're asking for a bit too much if you don't want it to be windows-specific. For example, on most systems, overly long pathnames are not directly usable, period. You have to manually `chdir` or use `openat` multiple times to reach the target file. So even if the library had no limit, the pathnames it returned would be of little use. Also, on non-windows systems, files do not have canonical names (POSIX has hard links)...

Comment: @Mehrdad: Extension is not just last dot to end of string. For example, in `/home/me/.config/foo`, the extension is empty, not `.config/foo`.

Comment: @Mehrdad: No. This case it actually handles correctly (it's more complicated than what I said), but I mean because of things like `myfile.dat:stream1:$DATA`. Extension is `.dat`, not `.dat:stream1:$DATA`. The sad thing is that the author tries to push his library to the C++ standard.

Comment: @ybungalobill: Ah! Good point, thanks. :)

Comment: @R.. : Windows (NTFS) systems no longer have canonical names, either. The best you can get is path renormalization (i.e. remove `\.\ ` and `\..\ `)

Answer (score 1):

[cwalk](https://likle.github.io/cwalk/) can do that. It's a small C path library.

Comment: Upvoting, but it seems buggy... e.g. doesn't seem to handle NTFS streams or attributes when finding extensions...

Comment: You are right, ADS isn't supported - however, is that even considered to be part of the path? Microsoft's [PathFindExtensionA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getextension?view=netframework-4.8) and [Path.GetExtension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-pathfindextensiona) don't seem to support that neither. It doesn't seem to be even [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/file-path-formats)?

Comment: Microsoft's path APIs are known to be buggy. They don't even all support paths longer than `MAX_PATH` characters (until recent partial changes). They can get pretty weird too. Try `dir /b "C:\Windows:$I30:$INDEX_ALLOCATION\Notepad.exe"` in the command prompt

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like [QDir](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdir.html) and [QFileInfo](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfileinfo.html) from [Qt 4](http://qt.nokia.com/).